# C# (UWP) - Access object dynamically from string-variable

Tags: c#, xaml, dynamic, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I've written some code that creates TextBlocks from a list of strings by calling a for loop:

```
List<string> menuPages = new List<string>() { "Home", "Media", "Settings" };
//method called from constructor:
private void createHeaders ()
{
    for (int i=0; i<menuPages.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBlock iheader = new TextBlock();
        iheader.Name = menuPages[i];
        iheader.Text = menuPages[i];
        if (i==pageIndex)
        { iheader.FontSize = 36; }
        else
        { iheader.FontSize = 32; }
        stacky.Children.Add(iheader); //Adding button to stack panel
    }
}
```

Now I've been writing another method that would cycle through each TextBlock in a loop and change the text to whatever I intend. I'd gotten a foreach loop working for the stackPanel children: (TextBlock tBlock in stacky.Children)
but I need to work with an indexed for loop. The code below is how I WANT to achieve this:

```
//Re-render headers
for (int i = 0; i < menuPages.Count; i++)
{
    //TextBlock menuPages[i].text = "foo";
}
```

Now of course the syntax above doesn't work so my question is, how can I address the TextBlocks from the strings in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have your textblocks created in a list. So, you can manipulate easily with indexed forloop.

```
List<string> menuPages = new List<string>() { "Home", "Media", "Settings" };
List<TextBlock> textBlocks = new List<TextBlock>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    createHeaders();
}

private void createHeaders()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < menuPages.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBlock iheader = new TextBlock();
        iheader.Name = menuPages[i];
        iheader.Text = menuPages[i];              
        iheader.FontSize = 32;
        textBlocks.Add(iheader);
        Stacky.Children.Add(iheader); 
    }
}

private void change_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < textBlocks.Count; i++)
    {
        textBlocks[i].Text = "foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems so obvious now making a second list but I looked past that as I figured it wouldn't register. Very pleased to have learnt this :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `StackPanel` only contains the `TextBlock` elements you are adding dynamically, you can access them this way as well:

```
foreach (var textBlock in Stacky.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
{
   textBlock.Text = "something";
}
```

This approach uses the `OfType<T>` LINQ extension method which filters the input collection by the specified type, so it only returns those children of `Stacky` that are a `TextBlock`.

If you have more content, in the `StackPanel`, then @Vignesh G's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Didn't quite address my need for indexing so I ended up using Vignesh's solution.
But thank you! It did help!